# Which software can replace ABC pdf?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

Currently, my server use ABC pdf to generetate PDF. but my client wants to change another software to generate PDF on the server (please see the list below) 
- PDF Split and Merge 
- CutePDF 
- PDFSam 
- ABBYY FineReader 
I do a lot of search on Google but it still not clear. Could you give me a recommendation and advices for this!
Currently, we are using ABCPdf for generating Pdf to users from doc files, image files, and to snapshot an URL then generate it to PDF.

Thanks and regards,

Comment: **a** this post probably should better be on the software recommendations stack exchange site. **b** why the [tag:pdfbox] tag? **c** for recommendations for your use case you should describe your user care more detailed.

Comment: thanks mkl, I have just update my question and remove pdfbox tag.

Comment: I don't have experience with the products you mention. But even if I had, I still could not recommend any because you don't explain *how* you generate pdfs. Are you starting with html and convert that to pdf? Or are you scanning and process the scanned images to pdfs? Are you filling in existing pdf forms? Or what? Different products might be recommendable for different use cases.

Comment: Hi mkl, 
Currently, we are using ABCPdf for generating Pdf to users from doc files, image files, and to snapshot an URL then generate it to PDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the main reason to replace the current SDK? Also, are you looking for free product or for a commercial one (like the one in question)?

If you are looking for PDF generation SDK, I suggest you to check ByteScout and its PDF SDK. It covers your requirements (at a first glance), can be deployed on the server side and also includes splitting, merging, url to pdf, html to pdf and image to pdf features. Also, it has a ton of C# samples on Github for almost all use cases. There is also a PDF Extractor SDK that can help you with converting images into searchable PDF files.

For more details please check:
https://bytescout.com/products/developer/pdfsdk/index.html

If you want to test things quickly before diving into using the SDK, there's a standalone PDF Multitool desktop tool based on the SDK:
https://bytescout.com/products/pdfmultitool/index.html

*Disclaimer: I work for ByteScout.*

Comment: thanks Razvan, I noted your answer, I will propose your suggestion to my team.